# Does shifting stop the Opportunity Attack benefit of Polearm Gamble?

Tags: dnd-4e

Does shifting stop the Opportunity Attack benefit of Polearm Gamble?

> **Benefit:** When a non-adjacent enemy enters a square adjacent to you, you can make an opportunity attack with a polearm against that enemy, but you grant combat advantage to that enemy until the end of the enemy’s turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The feat trigger is the enemy entering the square, not *moving* into the square. Because of the wording on the feat, even if the enemy was slid/pushed/pulled into the relevant square, it would trigger, as long as it was not adjacent to you at the start of their movement.

EDIT: Opportunity Attacks ([DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=331)) don't trigger if the enemy is using a shift, teleport, or being moved by forced movement. However, specific rules trumps general rules, and a feat is more specific than the general Opportunity Attack rules.

Other way to see this is that the feat is actually an Opportunity Action ([DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=119)), and as such, have its own trigger that do not care at all about Opportunity Attacks, that is only another opportunity action.

In either case, the answer remains the same: The wording on the feat allow you to make the attack as long as the enemy that started the movement non-adjacent to you enter an adjacent square, regardless of how he approached (except [Teleporting](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=86), that specifically rules out opportunity actions).

Comment: And as a note, in my games I rule that the move must be voluntary. Forced movement don't trigger the feat. The feat is still going strong between all my polearm users.